# How to change images using xamarin Localizing

Tags: c#, xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin and working on xamarin forms multilingual.i have convert my application in support to different languages using resource file but at the end i could'nt find the solution for images i also want to change image according to culture suppose i have different assets for different culture.can any one tell me help  regarding  this.

Comment: did you found a solution for your issue. I followed the guide but on iOS it is not working despite the fact than on Android everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There already is a good guide on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/#Localizing_Platform-Specific_Elements).

For iOS you should have a .lproj folder as you may already have if you have localised text already. You can then just add the localised image in there with the same name and it will be picked up automatically.

[image: lproj folders]

On Android you can just create localised subfolders under the Resources folder and also add localised image files with the same name.

[image: localised folders]

Comment: i am following the same and create the localised subfolder  for same but unable to get the result.

Comment: You can also have a look at the [accompanied sample app](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoLocalized) maybe that gives you some hint on what you should do more.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis the example gives a 404 not found from github

Comment: Updated the link :)

Answer (score 0):

At xamarin site is a good guid to this issue
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: i am following the same and create the localised subfolder for same and achived for text  but unable to get the result for image.